# How to apply date range filter on a type2 dimension table?

Tags: sql, tableau-api, dimensional-modeling

I have a tableau report which has start date and end date as parameters. 
I have a table which is type2 and has user's start date and user's end date. Sample data is as below

```
user_id  partner  user_start_date   user_end_date
U1       XYZ      2016-07-10        2016-07-23
U1       XYZ      2016-07-24        2016-07-30
U1       ABC      2016-07-31        2999-12-31
U2       ABC      2015-10-01        2999-12-31
```

Now I need to get all the valid users between the selected date range on a tableau report. I tried to apply below calculated field and filtered the report

```
    IF ( [Start Date] >= [User Start Date] 
         AND [Start Date] <= [User End Date] 
         AND [User End Date] >= [End Date] ) 
     OR    
    ( [User Start Date] >= [Start Date] AND
      [User Start Date] <= [End Date] AND
      [User End Date] >= [End Date]
    )
THEN 'Show' ELSE 'Hide' END
```

Wanted to know if this is right and if there is any other easy way.

Answer (score 0):

This should work better:

```
IF ([User Start Date] >= [Start Date] AND [User End Date] >= [Start Date])
   AND
   ([User Start Date] <= [End Date] AND [User End Date] >= [End Date])

THEN 'Show' ELSE 'Hide' END
```